# Flutter Black Space above keyboard when resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is true

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField when i set the property of resizeToAvoidBottomPadding in scaffold as True
when the keyboard is opened there is a space between keyboard and page content which i believe is part of scaffold but not part of body.
because the color of the space is same as backgroundColor of scaffold.

i have this problem only on Samsung note 10

```
Scaffold(
         resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
          body:  Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: TextField()
            ),
          );
```

[image: Before Focus TextField]

[image: After Focus TextField]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do not have another Scaffold as a parent to this Scaffold. Every scaffold creates its own space above the keyboard.